# Plug-in reference 'com.my.plugin.source' cannot be resolved in feature.xml

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I'm assembling a multi-module project to build a set of Eclipse plug-in (and a feature, an update site, etc.) with Tycho.

My issue is that for the *source* feature (the one that contains the source code of the plugin and can installed separately in addition to the plug-in) I have a warning in Eclipse:

```
Plug-in reference 'com.my.plugin.source' cannot be resolved in
feature.xml/com.my.plugin.source.feature
```

In the source `feature.xml` file I use the following definition:

```
<plugin
    id="com.my.plugin.source"
    download-size="0"
    install-size="0"
    version="0.0.0"
    unpack="false"/>
```

Any hints how can I resolve the warning? Thanks in advance!